# How do I find direct children and not nested children using Rails and Nokogiri?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with Ruby (2.3) and Nokogiri.  How do I find the most direct tr children of a table, as opposed to nested ones?  Currently I find table rows within a table like so …

```
  tables = doc.css('table')
  tables.each do |table|
    rows = table.css('tr')
```

This not only finds direct rows of a table, e.g.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>…</tr>
```

but it also finds rows within rows, e.g.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>This is found</tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

How do I refine my search to only find the direct tr elements?

Comment: Nokogiri implements CSS including some of the jQuery extensions so get familiar with how style sheets selectors work and you should have better luck. CSS is more readable but XPath is more powerful so knowing both is good. `tbody` tags are rarely used in generated HTML, however browsers tend to stick them in when you look at the page HTML. Don't trust the browser, instead look at the HTML directly using `wget` or `curl` or `nokogiri` at the command-line. Only use `tbody` if the raw HTML has it.

Comment: @Dave : Just curious : why would you accept an answer and not upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of steps using XPath. First you need to find the “level” of the `table` (i.e. how nested it is in other tables), then find all descendant `tr` that have the same number of `table` ancestors:

```
tables = doc.xpath('//table')
tables.each do |table|
  level = table.xpath('count(ancestor-or-self::table)')
  rows = table.xpath(".//tr[count(ancestor::table) = #{level}]")
  # do what you want with rows...
end
```

In the more general case, where you might have `tr` nested directly other `tr`s, you could do something like this (this would be invalid HTML, but you might have XML or some other tags):

```
tables.each do |table|
  # Find the first descendant tr, and determine its level. This
  # will be a "top-level" tr for this table. "level" here means how
  # many tr elements (including itself) are between it and the
  # document root.
  level = table.xpath("count(descendant::tr[1]/ancestor-or-self::tr)")
  # Now find all descendant trs that have that same level. Since
  # the table itself is at a fixed level, this means all these nodes
  # will be "top-level" rows for this table.
  rows = table.xpath(".//tr[count(ancestor-or-self::tr) = #{level}]")
  # handle rows...
end
```

The first step could be broken into two separate queries, which may be clearer:

```
first_tr = table.at_xpath(".//tr")
level = first_tr.xpath("count(ancestor-or-self::tr)")
```

(This will fail if there is a table with no `tr`s though, as `first_tr` will be `nil`. The combined XPath above handles that situation correctly.)

Comment: It's interesting to see how it can be done with xpath count, but it only works with `tag_a/tag_b/tag_a/tag_b` structure (for example `/table/tr/table/tr`), not with `tag_a/tag_b/tag_b`. The OP said he wanted to have a general answer.

Comment: @EricDuminil you can extend this technique to handle cases like `tag_a/tag_b/tag_b`. It’s a little more complex, but not much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind showing the corresponding solution? I really don't know much about xpath and would like to learn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit. I'm still not sure it works in the general case, though. Non-nested tr's could be at different depths in different branches of a table (as you said, it might not be valid HTML). As long as a tr node doesn't have another tr between table and itself, it should be returned.

Comment: @EricDuminil yes, but they would be nested under nodes other than `tr`. This code only looks at the nesting of `tr` elements, so it should work. I’ve added some comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could be done directly with css/xpath, so I wrote a small method which recursively looks for the node. It stops recursion as soon as it is found.

```
xml= %q{
<root>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr nested="false">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr nested="true">
              This is found</tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <another_table>
    <tr nested = "false">
      <tr nested = "true">
    </tr>
  </another_table>
  <tr nested = "false"/>
</root>
}

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)

class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def first_children_found(desired_node)
    if name == desired_node
      [self]
    else
      element_children.map{|child|
        child.first_children_found(desired_node)
      }.flatten
    end
  end
end

doc.first_children_found('tr').each do |tr|
  puts tr["nested"]
end

#=>
# false
# false
# false
```

Comment: It does not.  It fails if the HTML is a table followed by a tr (no tbody in between).

Comment: It wasn't clear in your example. Do you have both `table/tbody/tr` and `table/tr` ?

Comment: My quesiton is more genearl than that.  How do I select the trs in a table that are not nested within other trs?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this?

```
tables = doc.css('table')

tables.each do |table|
  rows = table.css('tr')

  rows.each do |row|
    if row.parent.parent == table
      # Some action here...
    end
  end
end
```